# Java - Not displaying print statement before getting user input with scanner (NetBeans issue?)

Tags: java, input, netbeans, printing, println

I'm trying to do a very simple user input in NetBeans 12.6 where I ask a question and have the user respond to it. Everything works fine when I use System.out.println("QUESTION") to display the question, but the code does not behave properly when I switch to System.out.print("QUESTION"). Full code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SimpleInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name: "); 
        String userName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your name is " + userName);
    }
}
```

Expected behaviour (and actual behaviour):

```
Enter your name: 
Ryan
Your name is Ryan
```

HOWEVER - when I switch to print instead of println, it waits for the user input BEFORE asking the question! Full code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SimpleInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name: "); 
        String userName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your name is " + userName);
    }
}
```

Desired behaviour:

```
Enter your name: Ryan
Your name is Ryan
```

Actual behaviour:

```
Ryan
Enter your name: Your name is Ryan
```

I'm supposed to be re-creating something for a university course in which the user input is gathered on the same line as the question, so simply using println instead of print isn't an option here. Based on other searches around SO, this might be an issue with NetBeans, rather than a problem in my code. However, this seems...crazy...that NetBeans would really not be able to correctly do something so simple, doesn't it?

Comment: I can't get your issue, but, putting `System.out.flush();` after the `print` statement might help

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  It works fine for me.

Comment: [1] I am also unable to reproduce your problem. [2] Update your question (rather than posting a comment) to detail the version of Java you are using, and how you created your project (Project type, Maven vs. Ant. vs. Gradle, etc.) That will help those who attempt to reproduce your problem. [3] What happens if you run your application from the command line rather than running within NetBeans (using **java -jar "{jar file}"**)? Do you still get the problem? [4] Not relevant for your issue, but FYI it's a very strong convention that you provide package a for your Java application.

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, but System.out.flush() isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using "Java with Maven".
And then I use "Java with Ant", instead of "Java with Maven ", when creating a project.
it solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).